# Django CMS migrate pages

Tags: python, django, django-cms

On my local machine I'm building a Django CMS site. I have about 50 CMS pages with page titles, custom slugs, and data. How do I dump just the CMS pages data on my local machine and load it into my staging environment?

I've tried using a fixture with python manage.py dumpdata cms.page --indent=2 > cmspages.json, however, the page title, slug, and data are not in the json so when I load cmspages.json the pages are created but no data is loaded.

How do I migrate my CMS pages to my staging environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link about South http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Link about how to integrate it with Django and start migrating your Database http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me:

`./manage.py dumpdata cms.page cms.title > pages.json`